# Multiple Resource Models for Rundeck Nodes

Tags: nodes, rundeck

I want to add two sources to my resource model in Rundeck nodes list. But is there any way to isolate the 2. Like the first one is an xml file which pulls data from an inventory manager and if and only if the file is empty it should go to the second type of resource model which should come from chef server.

I have added both the resource models to my node list but not sure which is getting used or both are coming and getting over ridden

Answer (score 0):

The enable/disable node sources based on indexes sounds interesting for an enhancement, maybe it is a good idea to create some script that keeps only one depends on your need through [Rundeck API](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/api/rundeck-api.html#updating-and-listing-resources-for-a-project).